# How to make Wireguard and Tasilscale coexist on the same machine?

Tags: vpn, wireguard, iproute2, tailscale

Seems that restarting the wg service always creates a routing table with higher priority than Tailsales which results in the inability to. connect to the machine via Tailscale until both services are stopped, firewall rules are flushed and services are started again.

I'd like to be able to test new wg configs and restart the service whenever without this procedure messing up my connectivity to the machine via Tailscale hostname.

I want to be able to access my machine via Tailscale IP or DNS name and also access other my Tasilscale machines via the same Tailscale's default 100.64.0.0/10 IP range.

I tried changing the Tasilscale routing table priority to 10, 1, 0, but whenever I restart wg servicece, restarting it interferes with Tailscale in a way that prevents me from connecting to the machine via the Tasilscale hostname.

**wg0.conf**:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = _redacted_
Address = 172.999.63.224/32,fd00:4956:504e:ffff::ac17:3fe0/128
DNS = 172.16.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = _redacted_
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0,::0/0
Endpoint = 95.999.95.19:2049
```

Tailscale config is the default one, basically just accepting traffic to/from their 100.64.0.0/10 IP range.

Don't know if I could provide more info, I'm pretty new to Wireguard tunnels and not sure why restarting it interferes with Tailscale in any way.